# ObJ Import Failure

Tags: objects

"System 19 Unavailable for OBJ error" Shows when I try to import OBJ models, I have never seen this before and its really weird... I have tried to do this multiple times and change file directory to another user account, but the error keeps the system in prone, Anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your Import Directory is set to =-5 in the system pref. Users set to +667, make sure all directory are tested and the file is system ed.

Comment: Could you clarify what is "Import Directory is set to =-5" and "directory are tested and the file is system ed"? Your answer seems quite unclear as to how it actually helps.